# Create polygon from a line

Tags: polygon, polyline-creation

I have searched high and low and cannot figure out how to do this...  I need to create a polygon based off a flight path, defined by radius to either side of the path.  For example, if an airplane flies from Madrid, to Paris, then to London, I'll have a line with three points.  I need to create a polygon around that line, extending out from either side of the line by a specified radius.  Example: given the black line between the three cities, my polygon would be roughly what's shown in orange.  Any suggestions on how I approach this?  My end goal will be to find whether specific points exist within the polygon (which I know how to do).

[image: Example]

Comment: Modeling for flight path often includes slip space for course correction after turn (outside the turn, for a nautical miles or two). If you can construct the parallel lines (as great circle routes), constructing a polygon is just saving the vertices as a list and a stack, then appending the popped stack to the list.

Comment: Using what software?

Comment: I am not using a specific software app.  Looking more for the algorithms.  This logic is going into a custom application.

Answer (score 1):

Create a buffer around your line. Use `Menu Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer` (see screenshot below).

Be aware that you use a proper CRS - one that is appropriate to measure distances. UTM zone 30 N / `EPSG:32630` might be a start, a custom CRS based on that even better.

[image]